# underscoreJS: using _.each() to do reduce(), map() etc

Tags: underscore.js

I was in a seminar where a discussion was brought up about using _.each() to do _.reduce(), _.map(), and _.filter() as an exercise to understand the concepts better.

I'm not even totally sure what this means, but I'm wondering if someone could clear this up for me?  How would one go about using _.each() to do _.reduce(), _.map(), and _.filter()?

Sorry if this is vague.

Comment: If you want to understand the concepts better, you should rather use `reduce` to implement `map`, `filter` and `each`,

Comment: Have you ever implemented one of these functions yourself (with native js only)? If not, you should start with that. If you have done so, please [edit] your question to show us your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take `_.map` as an example. `_.map` iterates over a collection, executing a function (iteratee) per item on that collection, building a new array out of the iteratee's return values.

```
_.map( [ 1, 2, 3 ], function ( val ) {
    return val * 2;
});
```

outputs `[ 2, 4, 6 ]`

To recreate the _.map functionality using `_.each` you could do something like this:

```
function map ( arr, iteratee ) {
    var newArray = [];
    _.each( arr, function ( val ) {
        newArray.push( iteratee( val ) );
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
map( [ 1, 2, 3 ], function ( val ) {
    return val * 2;
});
```